# How to set Keyboard Type in Xamarin android using MVVMCross?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm new to MVVMCross and trying to change keyboard type of Input field based on setting. I tried to achieve this by creating convertor but no luck. Please help me if you can.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MvvmCross. This is a view concern, out of the scope of what MvvmCross provides.

Comment: Agree that's why I asked here how we can do this in MVVMCross. As suggested by Adrain Zhu -MSFT, we can use True/False for 2 type but I was looking for something where we can return Keyboard type from convertor. I don't know why you downgrade my question instead of providing ans.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your keyboard with **Keyboard** property, as following shows

> ```
> Chat – used for texting and places where emoji are useful.
> Default – the default keyboard.
> Email – used when entering email addresses.
> Numeric – used when entering numbers.
> Plain – used when entering text, without any KeyboardFlags specified.
> Telephone – used when entering telephone numbers.
> Text – used when entering text.
> Url – used for entering file paths & web addresses.
> ```

Here is a document you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry

**Update:**

I bind the switch with Entry.Keyboard using Converter code like following:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="switch keyborad"/>
            <Entry BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">
                <Entry.Keyboard>
                <Binding Source="{x:Reference myswitch}"
                         Path="IsToggled">
                    <Binding.Converter>
                        <local:KeyboardConverter x:TypeArguments="Keyboard"
                                                 TrueValue="Keyboard.Chat"
                                                 FalseValue="Keyboard.Numeric"/>
                    </Binding.Converter>
                </Binding>
                    </Entry.Keyboard>
            </Entry>
            <Switch x:Name="myswitch"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

**Converter:**

```
 public class KeyboardConverter<T>:IValueConverter
    {
        public T TrueValue { set; get; }
        public T FalseValue { set; get; }
        public KeyboardConverter()
        {
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (bool)value ? TrueValue : FalseValue;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((Object)value).Equals(TrueValue);
        }
    }


    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
```

Comment: I want to bind it using MVVMCross with Entry field. I guess we need to write down our own convertor for this but I Didn't find any solution on this yet.

Comment: I wrote a sample page, you can refer to it.

Comment: Thank you, Let me try this in MVVMCross and update you.